# Mockito's argThat returning null when in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

Given the following class (written in kotlin):

```
class Target {
     fun <R> target(filter: String, mapper: (String) -> R): R = mapper(filter)
}
```

I'm able to test in java, the test code:

```
@Test
public void testInJava() {
    Target mockTarget = Mockito.mock(Target.class);
    Mockito.when(mockTarget.target(
            argThat(it -> true),
            Mockito.argThat(it -> true)
    )).thenReturn(100);
    assert mockTarget.target("Hello World", it -> 1) == 100;
}
```

The java test pass as expected, but the same test is written in kotlin:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val mockTarget = Mockito.mock(Target::class.java)
    Mockito.`when`(mockTarget.target(
            Mockito.argThat<String> { true },
            mapper = Mockito.argThat<Function1<String, Int>>({ true }))
    ).thenReturn(100)
    assert(mockTarget.target("Hello World") { 1 } == 100)
}
```

The kotlin version I receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockito.argThat<String> { true } must not be null
```

Why is it happening and how can I test that using kotlin?

Comment: Apparently there is an issue with nullable types... see here: https://medium.com/@elye.project/befriending-kotlin-and-mockito-1c2e7b0ef791

Comment: Thank you @GiacomoAlzetta you are right it is a null type issue, I'm able to solve following the medium post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2022, Mockito-Kotlin officially solves the problem.

The fix is very simple: Just import the `argThat`/`eq`/... from the `mockito-kotlin` package, instead of the `mockito` package, and everything is done!

Related: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying

Comment: Better late than never :D

Comment: It does not solve the issue for me. I'm using mockito-kotlin 4.0.0 and I'm still getting nullpointer when using argThat (import org.mockito.kotlin.argThat). Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: @the_dark_destructor maybe create a new stackoverflow issue with full code and error message

Comment: @ch271828n Solved it! The error disappear if you stop using `it` inside `argThat`.

So, if you use something like `argThat { it.someValue == "value"} ` you get an nullpointer. If you write `argThat { someValue == "value"} ` it works... shouldn't the two writings be equivalent? If that is the case I will open a new issue

Comment: @the_dark_destructor please show the full code. I am worried whether the `it` captures some closure outside it?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem.

And finally, I found `argThat()` will return null, and normally the argument in the function in kotlin, does not accept null type.

The source code of `argThat` from `ArgumentMatchers.java`

```
public static <T> T argThat(ArgumentMatcher<T> matcher) {
    reportMatcher(matcher);
    return null;
}
```

You can see that it `return null`. So when we mock the function, it will throw IllegalStateException, because `argThat` **returns null** and argument can't be null.

It mean that if your function is:

```
fun doSomething(arg1: String): Int {
    // do something
}
```

When you mock it like that:

```
Mockito.`when`(
    doSomething(Mockito.argThat<String> { true })
).thenReturn(100)
```

It will throw IllegalStateException

So you should change your function like that:

```
fun doSomething(arg1: String?): Int {
    // do something
}
```

**Change the "String" to "String?", make it accept null type.**

My solution is to define the argument with class? so that it can accept null, but I don't know if it is a great solution

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, could you give more details?

Comment: @ademar111190 simply put that you should change your function like this: target(filter: String?, mapper: (String?) -> R)...Then it can accept null type argument

Comment: @user3120237 In my tests it does not work. Look, I did upload the code of the question ready to run on GitHub: https://github.com/ademar111190/soq-test-mockito if you run the tests you can see the java passing and the kotlin failing, doing the changes you propose did not solve the problem. Fell free to try that by yourself.

Comment: @ademar111190  For your example, maybe you should change your function like that ```fun <R> target(filter: String?, mapper: ((String?) -> R)?): R? = mapper?.let { it(filter) }```, I'm sorry there is something error, I can't run. But for this change, It doesn't throw IllegalStateException

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, mockito-kotlin hasn't been updated for more than a year. As with all of these libraries, there's always a constant need for keeping them up-to-date, and I didn't want to get stuck with an unmaintained library.

So I came up with another way to solve the null issue with `argThat` without using any other libraries.

Say we've an interface `UuidRepository` as follows:

```
interface UuidRepository {
    suspend fun Entity save(entity: Entity): Entity
}
```

class `Entity` has two properties, `userId: String` and `uuid: String`.

The following code fails:

```
Mockito.verify(uuidRepository).save(argThat { it.userId == someValue && it.uuid == "test" })
```

with the error:

> argThat { it.userId == someValue && it.uuid == "test" } must not be null

To solve this, we get all the invocation on the mock and then verify the ones we want:

```
val invocations = Mockito.mockingDetails(uuidRepository).invocations
    .filter { setOf("findById", "save").contains(it.method.name) }
    .map { it.method.name to it.arguments }
    .toMap()

assertThat(invocations).containsKey("save")
val first = invocations["save"]?.first()
assertThat(first).isNotNull
val entity = first as Entity
assertThat(entity.userId).isEqualTo(someValue)
assertThat(entity.uuid).isEqualTo("test")
```